# How to get values from DB inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I am generating rows on clicking the Plus Button to add further rows in the table using javascript. Inside one of the cell I need to get value from the master table for the user to select it in Php  . I am not able to put php inside the script. How should I populate my values ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Could you please rephrase your question or add some screenshots of what you mean?

Comment: Use ajax and get data from server side and populate it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to get values from DB.( assuming you want to populate a dropbox with db values )

Comment: jQuery and AJAX are two entirely different things. jQuery happens to support AJAX, but it's not needed to do an AJAX request. Also, some further explanation other than "use this" would be useful.

Comment: Given how vaguely the question is formulated, I think it is unfair to bash on a vaguely formulated answer, that would certainly point the person in the correct direction.

Comment: @apriede Pointing someone in a possible right direction is not really an answer, it should be placed as a comment. Vague questions should be closed/put on hold, rather than being answered with something just as vague.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague and somewhat confusing, but from what I gather, you are looking for AJAX. AJAX can send data to a PHP script and receive a response all without reloading the page. To use AJAX, you have to have jQuery. Here is an AJAX example:

Assume you have this empty HTML paragraph and a button:

```
<p id="test"></p>
<button id="click">click me</button>
```

Next we can define that when the button is clicked, it fires the function getParaAjax().

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    getParaAjax();
});
```

Now we can define the function getParaAjax(), which includes the request.

```
function getParaAjax() {
        $.ajax({url: "example.php", 
        success:  function(result){
            $("#test").html(result);
        }});
}
```

That piece of code goes to example.php and then appends the response (the output of example.php) to the paragraph tag. In example.php, it looks up data from the database and then outputs it.

```
<?php
    //MySQLi connect code
    //MySQL select paragraph from text DB
    $result = "Hello, World!";
    echo $result;
?>
```

Then the final paragraph tag would look like this:

```
<p id='test'>Hello, World!</p>
```

Of course that PHP code wasn't legit, but from here, you can write a PHP script that outputs the data you need on your HTML page, and call it from AJAX using jQuery, and append it to your table or other place on the page, without refreshing. You can also send POST and GET data to your PHP page through AJAX and do many other things. Here are some links:

1. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm